# Session data file unexpectedly deleted before session.gc_maxlifetime and session.cookie_lifetime

Tags: php, session, cookies

On `Ubuntu 18.04.3` using `PHP v5.6.40`, active and unexpired session data files are being deleted by (I believe) PHP's garbage collection and/or the system's cron job `/etc/cron.d/php`, which contains the following:

```
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi
```

My understanding/assumption was that active and unexpired session data file cannot be deleted by either of those garbage collection systems.  So, why are my active session data files being deleted?

Here are my pertinent `php.ini` values:

- session.cookie_lifetime = 0
- session.cookie_path = /
- session.gc_divisor = 1000
- session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
- session.gc_probability = 1
- session.name = PHPSESSID
- session.save_path = /var/lib/php/sessions
- session.use_cookies = 1
- session.use_only_cookies = 1
- session.use_strict_mode = 1 (runtime, config is still 0)

Here are some details about one session data file that I was testing (PHPSESSID = `653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4`)

- CreationTime = "Mon, 11 Nov 2019 04:00:17 GMT"
- Expires = "Session"
- LastAccessed = "Mon, 11 Nov 2019 06:05:47 GMT"
- Path = "/"
- SameSite = Unset
- Secure = false

In order to see what activity was happening to the session data file, I entered the command:

```
sudo inotifywait -m -e modify,attrib,moved_to,moved_from,move,move_self,create,delete,delete_self --format '%:e %f %T' --timefmt '%H:%M' /var/lib/php/sessions/
```

...and the following results displayed over a period of time (PDT).

> ```
> CREATE sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:00
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:00
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:00
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:01
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:02
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:10
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:15
> MODIFY sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:15
> DELETE sess_653rd0gbeob59b35dc9jve71r4 23:17
> ```

There were no other files in the directory.  The aforementioned session data file was `CREATE`ed when my PHP script executed the session_start() at 23:00.  Each of the `MODIFY` actions occurred when I refreshed the web page or clicked on a menu item.  I expected/hoped that each `MODIFY` would restart the session timer and extend the duration of the current session and the cookie for another 1440 seconds (e.g., 23:15 + 1440 seconds = 23:39).  However, for an unknown reason, the `DELETE` occurred at 23:17.  I did not logout or F5 or anything different than what I did during the MODIFY actions I made.

Why did the session data file `DELETE` at 23:17 instead of 23:39?  Was it the cronjob or PHP's garbage collection?  If the session data file is active and in use, then why is it still able to be deleted, shouldn't it be locked while in use?

Also, in a previous test with another session data file, it was deleted at a time that coincides with the cronjob (it happened at ??:30), but that was only one instance.

I have read in multiple other posts that there are better alternatives for managing sessions, but I would like to understand and work through this issue before working around it and choosing one of the better options mentioned in other posts.

Comment: (Not the session _cookie_ was deleted, but the session _data file_. Garbage collection cleans up the latter.)

Comment: @04FS I edited my question accordingly, changing 'cookie' to 'session data file' throughout the post.  Thank you

Comment: Did you found the problem? I'm having similiar problem with session files being deleted after 48 or 72 hours